# Android studio user can choose color

Tags: android, color-picker

is there (androidstudio) any way to get color by user click on something like http://cdn.freshome.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/color-wheel.jpg ? It doesn't matter whether it be string,int or color.

Answer (score 0):

One way that i know it works is by duplicating an existent color res, for example:

```
<color name="window_background">#FFF5F5F5</color>
```

At the left of this line, there is a little square that displayed the color. Click on it and you can select another color. I don't know if there is other way of accomplish what you need.

EDIT: You asked for android studio, i answered accordingly. Based on your later comments the answer is NO. There is no default widget to do so (not that i know of). You would need to:

a) Make a ColorPicker yourself

b) Use a library like this: https://github.com/LarsWerkman/HoloColorPicker

Comment: I want to give to user the option to change color in application settings, not set color when application is created.